# VBA Formula If: WorksheetFunction, Formula, or R1C1?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

First post so please bear with me.

I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find any solution.

I'm trying to get either of these `If` formulas to work in VBA:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.If(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)> 0, "RECEIVES", "PAYS") 

ActiveCell.Formula = "= If(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) > 0, ""RECEIVES"", ""PAYS"")"
```

The first gives me error code 438, the second a `#NAME?` error as it displays the "Range..." text in the formula.

Using the macro recorder gives me this:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]>0,""RECEIVES"",""PAYS"")"`

I know the (desired) dfference between the first two, but what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `If` in `Application.WorksheetFunction`, that's why the 438 error. Use this instead:

```
ActiveCell.Value = IIf(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) > 0, "RECEIVES", "PAYS")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enter formula in a cell, then with VBA it's assigning some text to `Cells(row, column).Formula`. It get's tricky, when you want to insert certain cells there. One approach would be:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Address & ">0,""RECEIVES"",""PAYS"")"
```

where you simply concatenate - it's somewhat similair to your approach.

But VBA also provides more "clean" way of doing this (the one your macro has recorded):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2>0,""RECEIVES"",""PAYS"")"
```

The syntax inside the formula for offsets is like this:

`R[m]C[n]` is equivalent to `Offset(m, n)` (but the latter can't be used inside formula text), also you can omit the brackets `[]`.
In above example, `RC2` means `Offset(0 ,2)`.

Now, I'd recommend avoid `ActiveCell` and anything `Active` as much as possible. Instead you can use `Cell(row, column).Formula = ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

formula in cell cant be related to activecell.
You should do something like that:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "= If(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).address & " > 0, ""RECEIVES"", ""PAYS"")"
```

And there is no something like `Application.WorksheetFunction.If` you can use `iif(condition,value_true,value_false)` or use normal If-else block

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ActiveCell in a formula.  Try

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= If(RC[2] > 0, ""RECEIVES"", ""PAYS"")"
```

or for a range:

```
rngSomeRange.FormulaR1C1 = "= If(RC[2] > 0, ""RECEIVES"", ""PAYS"")"
'optionally turn formulae into constants
rngSomeRange.Value = rngSomeRange.Value
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I wasn't clear in my question, but I also need it to be dynamic, so that it works for different sized datasets as well. But I got the answer for that by other users.

Comment: that works just as well with a dynamic range ! An is probably much faster since you can enter it for a whole range at once, instead of looping cells.

Comment: So how would i write it if the column isn't always offset by 2?