# CountIf formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula, countif

I have a spreadsheet that has Agreement numbers (RA), but sometimes there are duplicate RA numbers because there is a second invoice (which is not unique).  I need to identify when there is a second invoice and add consecutive numbers before the RA number.  This formula does exactly that within a spreadsheet entered in Range D2
`=IF(E2=1,"1","" & COUNTIF(E2:E118,E2) & E2)`
and then fill down.  This creates a unique "RA" number for me, exactly what I need.

Now I'm trying to enter the same formula in a VBA sub.  I've tried the below, but I'm getting a sub or function not defined error:

```
Range("D2") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E2") = 1, "1", "" & CountIf(Range("E2:E" & vRow), Range("E2") & Range("E2")))
```

Here is the section of code for which I need assistance:

```
vRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
'Enter formula for unique invoice
Range("D2") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E2") = 1, "1", "" & CountIfs(Range("E2:E" & vRow), Range("E2") & Range("E2")))
'Range("D2").formula = "=IF(E2=1,"1","" & COUNTIF(E2:E118,E2) & E2)"
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Range("D2").FillDown
```

Any ideas on how to get the vba formula to work?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what the spreadsheet looks like?

Comment: At the start of your `Worksheetfunction` you're using `CountIf` instead of `If`.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your worksheet showing column `E` and the desired result in column `D`. The formula you have shared can be correct only for a single cell i.e. it is useless (try to copy it down to see for yourself). Also, what is the purpose of `""`? Also, share why you are messing with `.Calculation`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Range("D2") = IIf(Range("E2") = 1, "1", "" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E2:E" & vrow), Range("E2")) & Range("E2"))
```

- Excel WorksheetFunction hasn't If can use IIf

see [VBA Formula If: WorksheetFunction, Formula, or R1C1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979879/vba-formula-if-worksheetfunction-formula-or-r1c1)

- If only one criteria is defined, CountIf also can be used.
- The WorksheetFunction class has to be defined for CountIf. IIf is a VBA function.

If you want to place the formula programatically, see my comment.